# I can't see the error, but it says "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

when I go to this page I see this error (Null check operator used on a null value) instead of the content.

I have read questions that had the same error and in the answers they talked about one ! too many, but I could not figure out where the problem is in my code, perhaps the error refers to something else?
Can you help me find it please?

```
class PastTasksView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: Get.height,
        width: Get.width,
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 25, right: 25),
              child: Text(
                'Attività svolte',
                style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.012),
            GetBuilder<HomeController>(
              id: 1,
              builder: (controller) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final task = controller.pastTasks[index]!;
                      return Slidable(
                        // actionPane: SlidableBehindActionPane(),
                        // actionExtentRatio: 0.2,
                        // controller: controller.slideC,
                        child: ExpandedContainer(
                          icon: task.taskImage,
                          title: task.tasktitle,
                          time: task.startTime,
                          desc: task.taskDesc,
                          ifDate: true,
                          date: DateFormat.yMMMd().format(task.taskDate!),
                        ),
                        startActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: BehindMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                              onPressed: (context) {
                                // controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                                Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                controller.preUpdateTask(task);
                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  isScrollControlled: true,
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return BottomSheetContent(
                                      buttonText: 'Update Task',
                                      onSubmit: () {
                                        controller.updateTask(task);
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                ) as IconData;
                              },
                              label: "Update",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        endActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: BehindMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                              onPressed: (context) {
                                // controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                                Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                controller.deleteTask(task);
                              },
                              label: "Delete",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: controller.pastTasks.length,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Replying to comments:
1-Ok I pasted it here https://pastecode.io/s/92fo20qh

2- In logcat there is only this
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building GetBuilder(dirty, state: GetBuilderState#d36d0):
Null check operator used on a null value

3- to check the presence of contents

Comment: could you include your home controller

Comment: There’s usually a line number in the stack trace in the output logs  that should give you(us) a clue. Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: `controller.pastTasks[index]` what is this?

Comment: print the value of `task.taskDate` and confirm that you are not getting a `null` from this. If it gets `null` you are not filling this value correctly